# "Library containing this symbol is not referenced by the current project, so the symbol is undefined"

Tags: winforms, vb6, com-interop

I've added a reference to a C# DLL in a VB6 project. One C# function returns a value of type `DialogResult` which an enum defined in Windows Forms.

When I use Intellisense in VB6 to pick a value from `DialogResult` it asks me:

[image]

<sub>(*The library containing this symbol is not referenced by the current project, so the symbol is undefined. Would you like to add a reference to the containing library now?*)</sub>

If I click YES, it appears to do NOTHING. No changes are made to the VB6 project.

I can see from Object Browser that the enum is defined in:

```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.tlb
```

Which is what I assume should have been added to the project... but **what is going wrong, why doesn't it work?**

---

[The message above is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/the-library-containing-this-symbol-is-not-referenced-by-the-current-project-so-t) but it has very little useful to say.

Comment: @preciousbetine like many other people we have longstanding existing code to maintain. That's just reality, it wouldn't be my first choice by a long shot.